# What are the implications of the removal of HTTPClient in android M

Tags: android, networking, android-6.0-marshmallow

I started networking in android very recently and while looking for the best networking library I came across this one: [link](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) and in the `ReadMe` they mentioned this,

"**Recent removal of HttpClient in Android Marshmallow(Android M) made other networking library obsolete**".

Now I'm curious what exactly does that mean?Is it that we won't be able to use other networking libraries like `volley`,`retrofit` etc,or what exactly does it mean.

As for my current project i'm using this library 
`implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'` and I just tested it on android M and its working so i'm a bit confused.

Does the statement in the link hold water?

If so,what exactly does it imply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html)

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

So basically HTTP client was replaced by  HttpURLConnection class because it is faster and consume less battery power.
Which **DOES NOT** mean that you can not use volley,retrofit etc.

Comment: I didn't quite get your last statement.Can we or can we not use the other libraries?Yes or no?

Comment: **Yes**, you can !

Comment: OK nice.But still say a library I'm using doesn't include HttpURLConnection? can it then become obsolete or what was the whole point of that statement in that link about other libraries becoming obsolete?

Comment: other libraries becoming obsolete? where did you see that ?

Comment: See in the link in my post

Comment: let me put the statement in bold in my question

Comment: I am not sure in what context they said that. I think you can ignore that.
I user Retrofit all the time, using since last 2 years.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168182/discussion-between-thekamble-and-manish-gupta).